# Input impedance of Op amp calculation

Tags: integrated-circuit, input-impedance

As a part of my project I created an CMOS Op amp and I want to go through all parameters. In Op amps data sheet there are terms like input bias current and input impedance. How this terms are calculated? Please explain.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In data sheets, often the test circuit used is shown.  Find such a data sheet

Comment: How did you create a CMOS opamp without thinking on these parameters in the first place?

Comment: This list would be rather large and would take a very long time to answer. Your question is too broad.

Comment: If you Google it, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here. The datasheet for the device or similar device should show a setup of how it has been measured or determined.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because insufficient research.

Answer (score 1):

Analog Devices published a training seminar in which they talk all about Op Amp Input Bias Current. You should check it out here: http://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-038.pdf

On page four they answer your question on calculating input bias current. It is really something *measured* not so much calculated. Generally speaking they put a high series resistance in line with the input, and measure the voltage drop across it (by observing induced offset voltage). If the input bias current is low, they charge a capacitor with the bias current and measure the rate of charge.

Input impedance is again calculated with a series resistance, and when the voltage drop across the series resistor is exactly half of the input impedance, the series resistor is equal to the input impedance. This makes sense when you think about it as a voltage divider, when both resistors are equal the voltage drop is (1/2)*Vin. Here's another resource to use the has both a calculator, and a model for calculating input and output impedance: http://www.sengpielaudio.com/calculator-InputOutputImpedance.htm

Comment: Thanks for your response Josh, Mine is an CMOS based op amp. You have posted BJT op amp related stuff...